# Treeview Slow in IE?

Tags: asp.net, performance, treeview, updatepanel

I have a treeview with around 200 records that needs to be fully expanded at all times (so no loading on demand).  It is inside of an update panel with the updatemode set to conditional.  There are other update panels on the page as well that are set to conditional.  Depending on user actions the tree may need to be rebuilt by calling databind and updating the updatepanel.  Everything works fine in firefox, longest postback about 2 seconds.  With IE I have to wait up to 30 seconds sometimes and the action may have nothing to do with the tree just changing a dropdown in its own updatepanel takes forever.  I have considered the size of viewstate and just raw HTML generated may be causing the delay but wouldn't that  effect both browsers?  Anyone have anyideas what is making it so slow in IE???  Thanks!

Comment: I thought the TreeView control was not officially supported for use within an updatepanel?  I know this doesn't answer your question (which is probably something to do with how IE handles JS), but you may want to check into known issues with this configuration.

Comment: Tried removing the updatepanel, still slow in IE :(